# LINQ TO DataSet: Multiple group by on a data table

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, dataset, group-by

I am using Linq to dataset to query a datatable. If i want to perform a group by on "Column1" on data table, I use following query

```
var groupQuery = from table in MyTable.AsEnumerable()
group table by table["Column1"] into groupedTable

select new
{
   x = groupedTable.Key,
   y = groupedTable.Count()
}
```

Now I want to perform group by on two columns "Coulmn1" and "Column2". Can anybody tell me the syntax or provide me a link explaining multiple group by on a data table??

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should create an anonymous type to do a group by multiple columns:

```
var groupQuery = from table in MyTable.AsEnumerable()
group table by new { column1 = table["Column1"],  column2 = table["Column2"] }
      into groupedTable
select new
{
   x = groupedTable.Key,  // Each Key contains column1 and column2
   y = groupedTable.Count()
}
```