# LINQ to DataSet Group By Multiple Columns - Method Syntax

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0, linq-to-dataset

My question is identical to two previously asked questions

[LINQ TO DataSet: Multiple group by on a data table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225710/linq-to-dataset-multiple-group-by-on-a-data-table), the only difference with this question is that I need to do that with Method Syntax.
and

[LINQ Group By Multiple fields -Syntax help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869001/linq-group-by-multiple-fields-syntax-help) - the difference with this question is that I need to do this using LINQ-to-DataSet.

I'm trying to group the Customers by Country, with the result (expected) as below:

```
   COUNTRYCODE     CUSTOMERNAME
   USA             Microsoft   
   USA             IBM
   CAN             RIM
   CAN             Tim Horton
   GER             BMW
```

How do we do this?  Thank you.

EDIT:

Here's the messy code I'm struggling with.

```
   var query = orders.AsEnumerable()
                    .GroupBy(t => new {CountryCode= t.Field<string>("CountryCode"), 
                                       CustomerName = t.Field<string>("CustomerName"), 
                                    (key, group)=> new {Key1 = key.CountryCode, Key2=key.CustomerName})
                    .Select(t => new {t.Key1, t.Key2});
```

Comment: What do you mean with "with the result (expected) as below"? The result is not grouped by country.

Comment: I should have said, "grouped by (Country + Customer)" Sorry.

Comment: You already have an example with Linq to DataSet, and an example for the extension method syntax. You just have to combine them... what else do you need?

Comment: @FMFF: You should also have added some sample data, not only the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in my EDIT worked:

```
 var query = orders.AsEnumerable()   
              .GroupBy(t => new {CountryCode= t.Field<string>("CountryCode"),
                                 CustomerName=t.Field<string>("CustomerName"),
                           (key, group)=> new {CountryCode = key.CountryCode,CustomerName=key.CustomerName})
.Select(t => new {t.CountryCode, t.CustomerName});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var uniqueCountryCustomer =
         tblCustomer.AsEnumerable()
        .GroupBy(row => new
        {
            Country = (string)row["COUNTRYCODE"],
            Customer = (string)row["CUSTOMERNAME"]
        });
```

For the sake of completeness, here is the query-syntax:

```
var uniqueCountryCustomer = 
            from row in tblCustomer.AsEnumerable()
            group row by new{
                Country=(string)row["COUNTRYCODE"],
                Customer=(string)row["CUSTOMERNAME"]
            };

// display result
var summary = from cc in uniqueCountryCustomer
              select string.Format("Country:{0} Customer:{1} Count:{2}", 
              cc.Key.Country, 
              cc.Key.Customer, 
              cc.Count());
MessageBox.Show(string.Join(Environment.NewLine,summary));
```

Comment: BTW, the OP specifically asked for the method syntax, not the query comprehension syntax...

Comment: @Thomas: I've read method syntax but understood query, sorry. Removed the `into Group`. Normally coding in VB.NET, so this is collateral damage of my C# training ;)