# Group elements by count in IEnumerable

Tags: .net, group-by, ienumerable

How can we get the counts of rows by the value of a given column?

- I am creating IEnumerable from datatable returned from stored procedure

  ```
      DataSet ds = new DataSet();
      // code to get table using sp    
      IEnumerable<DataRow> Myrows = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable();
  ```
- My table returns data like

  ```
     Id | Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
      1 | xCol1   | xCol2   | xCol3   |
      2 | xCol1   | xyy     | ser     |
      3 | xCol2   | 2324    | ser     |
  ```
- now i want to get count of rows with group by Column1 .   So my result should be

  ```
      Count | Column |
        2   | xCol1  |
        1   | xCol2  |
  ```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Howto: Count the items from a IEnumerable<T> without iterating?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168901/howto-count-the-items-from-a-ienumerablet-without-iterating)

Comment: I think you are asking the same thing as this question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225710/linq-to-dataset-multiple-group-by-on-a-data-table

Comment: Thanks Chrisopher. you are right. i was looking for same thing you suggested

Comment: var groupQuery = from table in MyTable.AsEnumerable()
group table by new { column1 = table["Column1"],  column2 = table["Column2"] }
      into groupedTable
select new
{
   x = groupedTable.Key,  // Each Key contains column1 and column2
   y = groupedTable.Count()
}

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this:

1. Iterate over the `IEnumerable` collection and count the elements.
2. If you don't want to iterate, use `Myrows.ToList().Count` which will create a list from the `IEnumerable` collection and get the `Count` property of the List.

You can use linq to do the group by and get the count from there. Here is an example:

```
var groups =
  from row in rows
  group rows by row.Column;

foreach (var group in groups)
  Console.WriteLine("key: {0} count: {1}",
    group.Key, group.Count());
```

Also see this question for more information: [Howto: Count the items from a IEnumerable without iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/168901/213159)

Answer (score 0):

```
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    // code to get table using sp    
    var grouped = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().GroupBy(q=>q.Table.Columns["column1"]).Select(q=> new{Count = q.Count(), Column = q});
```

I've not tried it. But something like that.